# Configure Postgres to use double quotes as string delimiters

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, apache-spark

We are dealing with streaming data coming into us over kafka - use scala / spark streaming to read, process and write to postgres db tables. Some of the attributes (who provide text content) might send us free text which might contain quotes of different types.

As such, we can write escaping / replacing methods to clean the text up and insert into postgres. However, given that we are dealing with an streaming environment, and string handling methods are typically slower, we want to avoid using them.

I am wondering if there are any session commands in postgres, using which i can tell postgres session manager that for this current session, double quotes dont represent column name, instead they represent string. something similar to SET commands in sql server / oracle session management context.

Comment: No, there is no such thing.

Comment: This should be something the driver you are using to connect to Postgres  should handle.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver We are using JDBC Drivers. will surely check the driver capabilities.